# VBA- clearing the contents of previously filled cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 column table with columns as bunker index and bunker name.. i have to index the bunker using VBA and then generate another table with columns as the Bunker names and 'first column as the date... 
On changing the number of bunkers( like from 10 to 8).. the color of the cells(last 2 columns previosly filled) in second table remains the same (blue), which i require as default (white)

I have used many variables from my workbook. Any suggestion in this regard. As to how should the formatting be done?

**This is the Code :**

```
Sub Bunker_index_Click()
    Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Cells(4, 6), Sheet3.Cells(500, 100)).ClearContents

    Dim N As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim LocalIYM As Date
    LocalIYM = ThisWorkbook.IYM
    N = Application.CountA(Range("B:B")) - 1
    ThisWorkbook.NumBunker = N
    MsgBox (N)
    Cells(5, 1).Value = "Bunker Index"

    For i = 1 To 100
        If i <= N Then
            Cells(5 + i, 1).Value = i
            Cells(5 + i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(253, 233, 217)
            Cells(5 + i, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(219, 238, 243)
        Else
            Cells(5 + i, 1).ClearContents
            Cells(5 + i, 2).ClearContents

        End If

    Next i

        Range("F5").Value = "Time (LOCKED)"
        Range("F5").Interior.Color = RGB(253, 233, 217)
        For i = 1 To 100
            If i <= N Then
                Cells(5, 6 + i).Value = Cells(5 + i, 2)
                Cells(5, 6 + i).Interior.Color = RGB(253, 233, 217)
            Else
                Cells(5, 6 + i).ClearContents         ' unable to bring back th original
                                                      ' color of the cells

            End If

        Next i

    For k = 1 To 12 * 1
        If k <= ThisWorkbook.N Then
             Cells(k + 5, 6).Value = LocalIYM
             LocalIYM = DateAdd("m", 1, LocalIYM)
             Cells(5 + k, 6).Interior.Color = RGB(253, 233, 217)            ' problem handling borders
           '  Range("B2").Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlDashDot

         '    1edgeleft).LineStyle = x1linestyle.x1countinous

             For j = 1 To N
                Cells(5 + k, 6 + j).Interior.Color = RGB(219, 238, 243)
             Next j

        Else
             Sheet2.Cells(i + 4, 6).Clear
        End If
    Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe that first command should be .Clear instead of .ClearContents?

Comment: Ya,  tried that too, but it doesn't work as well.
Anyways, i found the bug, the thing is i am clearing the "contents" of the cell only. I need to clear the background of the cells as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.clear` or `.clearcontents` Try:

```
.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
```

Comment: I take it that worked then? Please accept or upvote answers if they are useful :)

Comment: Sorry,I didn't check whether it worked or not. Would check it asap. Would you mind helping me on another question that I posted related to Pivot Tables and user defined functions? would be really appreciable. :)